# Is there a square-filling curve?

Tags: general-topology

How can an image of [0,1] fill a square? It seems to me that it would have to be DISCONTINUOUS, so it wouldn't satisfy the definition of a curve.

Comment: It may seem that it would have to be discontinuous, but in fact it doesn't.  There are continuous functions $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ which are surjective.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_filling_curve for an introduction, and feel free to ask back with questions about what you read.

Answer (score 6):

The space filling curve is in itselft the limit of a process,iteraded infinitely many times. They key here is that the function built are surjective functions to the limit, which mean they fill the space.You can check out for example [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) which gives an introduction to Peano's curve.